# Options for Bundling a Python web server in Electron?

Tags: python, numpy, electron, electron-packager, pyoxidizer

What are some options for packaging a python web server (i.e. flask, tornado, quart, sanic, etc.) that uses numpy inside an electron application?

I took a look at PyOxidizer, but could not find any examples in the documentation to suggest that this is possible with it.

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158738/python-on-electron-framework

Comment: It's unspecific. There's are many Python packaging tools, such as PyInstaller, PyOxidizer, py2exe, etc. You need to evaluate them, choose one, and ask a specific question if you confront a problem. Anyway here's my opinion - I would not use any Python packaging tool because Electron  provides the built-in packaging tool.

Comment: @relent95 "Electron provides the built-in packaging too" - do you mean to just include a python virtualenv in the electron bundle? What about numpy and openblas?

Comment: You create a ```requirements.txt``` with ```pip freeze```, install a fresh new Python distribution in a specific root directory, install all the required packages with the ```pip``` in that root directory and the previously created ```requirements.txt```, and package that root directory with Electron.

Comment: You maybe need to set environment variables, such as ```PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1```.